# A question on Brahmagupta Identity

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The Brahmagupta Identity states that

$$
\begin{align}
N & = (a^2+nb^2 )(c^2+nd^2 ) \\
  & = (ac-nbd)^2+n(ad+bc)^2 \\
  & = (ac+nbd)^2+n(ad-bc)^2 \\
\end{align}
$$

Knowing only $N$, is there a way to find $n$ such that the two cofactors of $N$ (not necessarily prime) can each be represented in the form $x^2 + ny^2$.

Any $n$ that is a solution must satisfy the condition

$$
\begin{align}
N & \equiv (ac + nbd)^2  & \mod {n} \\
  & \equiv k^2 & \mod {n}
\end{align}
$$

i.e., $N$ is a quadratic residue modulo $n$.

Also,
$$
\begin{align}
N & \equiv (ac + bd)^2 + (ad - bc)^2  & \mod {(n-1)} \\
  & \equiv u^2 + v^2 & \mod {(n-1)}
\end{align}
$$

i.e., $N$ must be the sum of two quadratic residues modulo $n-1$.

Assuming, the factorization of $N$ is unknown,

**Q1:** Are there any other conditions that can help with finding such candidate $n$ efficiently (and eliminating ones that are not fit)?

**Q2**: Does an $n$ always exist for all $N$ or are there any obstructions?

Comment: what do you want to happen if $N$ is prime?

Comment: @WillJagy, you may assume that $N$ is composite.

Comment: "The two factors of $N$?" There are, in general,  multiple ways to factor a number.

Comment: vvg,  take a look at   theorem 2 in   http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Brillhart_Euler_factoring_2009.pdf

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, sorry. Assume cofactors, not necessarily prime.

Comment: vvg, I guess the best thing is if you work up some numerical examples, numbers $N$ of modest size, and show us what you hope happens.  There are some rules:  if $N = u^2 + n v^2  $  and $N$ is divisible by prime $p$  with $p = s^2 + n t^2,$  then $N/p$  can also be written as $N/p = x^2 + n y^2 $   On the other hand, if $h(-4n) \neq 1$  we get few other assurances.

Comment: Maybe this will help: $(2 x^2 + 3 y^2)(2 z^2 + 3 w^2) = X^2 + 6 Y^2$  for numbers $X,Y$  you may work out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with your second question. Surely not all integers can be expressed as $x^2 + ny^2$, unless we allow for trivial solutions with $x=0, y=1, n=N$.

Comment: @EricSnyder, to clarify Q2: Say $N = x^2 + ny^2$. Are there composite $N$ (i.e., we know they have non-trivial factors) where the factors cannot be represented in that form for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @vvg  N = 35  fails your question 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$N=35$   is represented as $x^2 + n y^2 $   for
$$  n = 10, 19,  26, 31, 34, 35  \; .  $$

In particular, it is not represented by $x^2 + y^2, x^2 + 2 y^2, x^2 + 3 y^2, x^2 + 4 y^2, x^2 + 5 y^2$

For any of the $n$ above, $5,7$   are not represented by $x^2 + n y^2 $

Same idea for $$N = 55583= 11 \cdot 31   \cdot 163  $$

which is represented as $x^2 + n y^2 $ for

$$  n =       358, \;  827, \;  1294, \; 1759, \; 2222, \; 2683, \ldots  $$
but for no smaller $n.$